# XMPP Room Creation Denied (403)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xmpp

I am trying to create a chatroom in XMPP (cloned from [ChatSecure](https://github.com/ChatSecure/ChatSecure-iOS) which is not letting me create my chatroom.This is the response I get while creating a chat room.

```
<presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="16d8ecb3-ce47-42cb-90aa-cbd9eade37ac@conference.myServer/92313456778@myServer" to="92313456778@myServer/phone" type="error"><x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"/><x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update"><photo>f0858329475df2054ad8e8ac8674e7b4f25aedcd</photo></x><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework" ver="yE4evQDERI5tsQRBmzG1547iiAU="/><error code="403" type="auth"><forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">Room creation is denied by service policy</text></error></presence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the response I see from="16d8ecb3-ce47-42cb-90aa-cbd9eade37ac@conference.myServer/**92313456778@myServer**".  That's why I asked you for what did you sent out.

I guess you set the `full JID` (92313456778@myServer) as nickname for the room, which includes an `@`, and I think it's not allowed.

Let's assume:

- user = user123
- host = myServer
- resource = myDevice
- mucService = conference.myServer
- roomName = myRoom
- nickname = johndoe (**Do not include `@`**)

In your request, `from` and `to` should be:

- from = user123@myServer/myDevice
- to = room@conference.myServer/johndoe

Comment: No. this was not the error. The room id creating issues.

Comment: Don't know it's about length or something else but reducing length of id resolved this issue.

Comment: I don't think the length of roomName is the issue, myself also use guide as roomName.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. But problem was resolved when I replaced UUID.String to some user entered text.

Comment: Well, let's say length is the issue, have you try use jid.user instead of jid.full as the nickname? That's removing the @myServer.  And then still use guid as roomName, see what happens.